# Java changing upper or lower case by entering CAPS

Tags: java, arrays, string

i want to write a program which at first it gets an integer number which is the number of strings of characters that are supposed to be entered including CAPS and i want that after each CAPS that was entered the rest of characters change in upper or lower case (the default is lower case at first) and finally the program outputs the final string. here is an example:
input:

```
8
s
f
k
CAPS
h
j
CAPS
p
```

output:

```
sfkHJp
```

here is what i tried so far first i wanted to check out whether this algorithm will work out or not but it actually did not because it does not print the result at all !

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int CAPScounter = 0;
        String result = "";
        String temp = "";
        String singles = "";
        boolean CAPSval = false;

        if (CAPSval) {
            singles = "CAPS";
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        // System.out.print(n);

        while (true) {
            if (result.length() == n - CAPScounter) {
                break;
            }
            //temp += input.next();
            singles = input.next();
            if (CAPSval) {
                CAPScounter += 1;
                result += temp;
                temp = "";
            }
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never change `CAPSval` from false to true.

Comment: Your `CAPSval` is always false and that means you never append `temp` to the result. And even if `CAPSval` magically changed to `true`: you never assign anything but an empty string to `temp` and therefore the `result` will never change.

Comment: The criterion for quitting the loop is wrong - it shouldn't be based on the length of `result`, you should just be looping `n` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a simple solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        String singles = "";
        boolean isCAPSEnabled = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();

        while (n-- > 0) {
            singles = input.next();
            if (singles.equals("CAPS")) {
                isCAPSEnabled = !isCAPSEnabled; // reverse
            } else {
                result += isCAPSEnabled ? singles.toUpperCase() : singles.toLowerCase(); 
            }
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the condition in the while loop assumes that each token is only one character long. It would break too soon if they are longer. Just loop n times, it's easier.

Comment: Makes sense. Updated! In this case we also don't need the `CAPScounter`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can set limit for while
2. CAPSval if first button second it value equal false or true
3. if CAPSval == true single change to Upper else toLower
4. if n == 0 while end and output result
5. Sorry I update solution you nofify first time button caps and If not button caps you enter upper or lower character then output same with enter

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int CAPScounter = 0;
        String result = "";
        String singles = "";
        boolean CAPSval = false, fistButton = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        while (n-- > 0) {
            singles = input.next();
            if (singles.equals("CAPS")) {
                fistButton = true;
                CAPSval = !CAPSval;
                CAPScounter += 1;
            } else {
                if (fistButton) {
                    if (CAPSval)
                        singles = singles.toUpperCase();
                    else singles = singles.toLowerCase();
                }
                result += singles;
            }

        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```